# how do i close the socket from within the java apache server HttpRequestHandler.handle() to reject an upload?

Tags: java, android, apache-httpcomponents

I have a java (android) app that runs an HTTP server using the apache HTTP framework (which ships with android).

Inside my `handle(HttpRequest req, HttpResponse resp, HttpContext ctx)` method I do some logic to decide whether I want to accept a PUT request or not.

If I decide to reject the upload, I can do a `consumeContent()` on the Entity (or even a `getContent().close()`) but on the client side I still see the upload continue.

I'd really like to save the bandwidth and just close the socket, but I don't know how to get access to the socket from inside the handle() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this problem is to throw an exception, which will result in an HTTP error message being sent back to the client and will close the server-side socket.

Comment: Then I was forced to disable the Apache client retry.  Fortunately, that can be done with setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(0, false));